# In the formula for the conservation of mechanical energy, what does mean the velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, velocity

For example I have the formula:
MEI=MEF
mgh+mvi2/(2)=mgh+mvf2/(2),
What does initial and final velocity mean?

Comment: Use MathJax, it makes the sight work better and increases participation.

Answer (score 1):

So you write that:
$$mgh+{1\over 2}mv_i^2=mgh+{1\over 2}mv_f^2.$$
However, for a conservative force the principle of conservation of energy usually reads:
$${1\over 2}m(v_f^2-v_i^2)=-\Delta U.$$
Where $v_i$ denotes the initial speed of the system and $v_f$ denotes the final speed of the system. In your case, $\Delta U=0$, since $\Delta U=mg(h-h)$. Thus, we have that:
$${1\over 2}m(v_f^2-v_i^2)=0\implies v_f=v_i.$$
Basically, nothing is happening in your example. If however, you meant to write:
$${1\over 2}m(v_f^2-v_i^2)=-mg(h_f-h_i),$$
then the principle of conservation of energy allows one to calculate the initial and final velocities respectively:
$$v_i=\sqrt{2g(h_f-h_i)+v_f^2},$$
$$v_f=\sqrt{2g(h_i-h_f)+v_i^2}.$$